# youtube reporting api Internal error encountered., youtube-analytics-api

Tags: youtube-analytics-api

I use the youtube bulk reports (youtube analytics and reporting api) and get few of the reports on a daily basis , by first listing the reports available for the jobs I have defined and then downloading. The API call made to list the reports available "https://youtubereporting.googleapis.com/v1/jobs/{jobId}/reports" is consistently giving 500, Internal error for the whole day ( 5/14/2017) , where as the query to list jobs does give the required list of jobs (https://youtubereporting.googleapis.com/v1/jobs). I have tried this from my code which has been working for past several months as well as from the Oath Playground tool. 
Questions
(a) How does one get more information when this happens, the error in documentation just asks to try later
(b) Is there a place we can see the status of youtube-analytics-api health, so that we know there is a production issue , if any